# How to add new EMF records to an exist Windows EMF File?

Tags: c++

I can display EMF Records,But I do not know how to add new EMF records to an exist Windows EMF File.Somebody can help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tools which can do this:
Here are some tools available which can edit EMF records:
1) [EmfExplorer](http://frazmitic.free.fr/emfexplorer/)
2) [libEMF C/C++ Library](http://libemf.sourceforge.net/)
3) [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)
4) [Metadraw](http://www.bennet-tec.com/btproducts/MetaDraw/MetaDraw.htm)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again,I read a part of inkscape source code,But I can't find the method of edit emf records,can you give me some suggestions.thanks